# Listener of a RecyclerView being apply to others RecyclersView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener, event-listener

Well, I'm working with Kotling right now, and I've a listener in `onBindViewHolder` inside the `ViewHolderAdapter`, but, the behavior of this listener is being applied at each 10 positions. The behavior is just to change a image color using a color filter when I touch that image. Pretty simple.

I've tried to use `holder.setIsRecyclable(false)` but when the Recycler get out of the screen, the image gets to it's normal design, and not more red.

Here's my `ViewHolderAdapter`

```
class ViewHolderAdapter(private var products:List<EachProduct>):RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolderAdapter.ViewHolder>(){

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent:ViewGroup,viewType:Int):ViewHolder{
        val view=LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_layout,parent,false)
        return ViewHolder(view)

    }

    override fun getItemCount():Int{

        return products.size

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder:ViewHolder,position:Int){
        //holder.setIsRecyclable(false)
        holder.likeImage.setOnClickListener{ 
            holder.likeImage.setColorFilter(Color.RED) 
        }   

    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView:View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

        var likeImage:ImageView=itemView.LikeImage

    }

}
```

I expected that only the image of the touched RecyclerView change, not, for example, at every 10 rows. Can someone provide me an example on how to set a listener inside a image in a RecyclerView?

Comment: `RecyclerView` recycles views as you scroll. Store selected index in a variable and check it during `onBindViewHolder`.

Comment: Refer https://android.jlelse.eu/android-handling-checkbox-state-in-recycler-views-71b03f237022

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ImageView.setColorFilter()` assigns a `ColorFilter` object to a field of the `ImageView`. This means that when your `ViewHolder` is recycled and re-bound to a new image, the `ColorFilter` is still in place and will apply to whatever image is loaded in.

Additionally, there's no guarantee that the same `ViewHolder` will be used for the same position if you scroll up and down.

What you need to do is somehow store *inside your data set* whether or not the image should have a filter applied to it. For example, maybe you store the last clicked position:

```
var lastClickedPosition = -1

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    if (position == lastClickedPosition) {
        holder.likeImage.setColorFilter(Color.RED)
    } else {
        holder.likeImage.setColorFilter(null)
    }

    holder.likeImage.setOnClickListener { 
        val previousPosition = lastClickedPosition
        lastClickedPosition = position
        notifyItemChanged(position)

        if (previousPosition != -1) {
            notifyItemChanged(previousPosition)
        }
    } 
}
```

Or maybe you want to be able to apply the filter to multiple rows at once. Then perhaps you could add a field to whatever list backs your adapter, or create a mutable set of highlighted positions:

```
val clickedPositions = mutableSetOf<Int>()

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    if (clickedPositions.contains(position)) {
        holder.likeImage.setColorFilter(Color.RED)
    } else {
        holder.likeImage.setColorFilter(null)
    }

    holder.likeImage.setOnClickListener {
        clickedPositions.add(position)
        notifyItemChanged(position)
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer!!